# awk - Pass arguments (ARGV) and file to parse in the same command

Tags: parameters, awk, arguments

I am running ubuntu11.10, and I think it uses mawk by default. Suppose I have an awk script named 'script.awk', it receives one argument. Also I want to specify the name of the file I want to parse. So if I would use '10' as an argument to parse 'file', I should run:

```
./script.awk 10 file
```

However '10' gets interpreted as a file to parse, and not as the argument. I know I could use the -v flag to set an internal variable, but I would like to use ARGV to be able to check if the argument was passed, like:

```
if (ARGC < 2) { exit 1 }
```

Is there a workaround, or I will have to stick the -v flag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BEGIN block in an awk script is executed before the arguments are used.  That gives you an opportunity to check for the right number of arguments and make changes.  There is a special behavior that if the argument is an empty string, it is skipped over, so you can do this:

```
  BEGIN {
    if (ARGC<3) exit(1);
    arg=ARGV[1]
    ARGV[1]=""
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Added to the above comment (after adding BEGIN) need to find the right awk.

We have versions of awk(as nawk,gawk).
Try to find using man(or help) to find in which version ARGC and ARGV are falling in which AWK commmand.
Use that respective AWK.

```
nawk 'BEGIN{if(ARGC>9) print "it ll get print . as i used NAWK" }' 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

**output :**

`it ll get print . as i used NAWK`

```
awk 'BEGIN{if(ARGC>9) print "It throw error . as i used AWK " }' 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

**output:**

`awk: can't open 1`